# Append value from dropbox to cell with semicolon

Tags: excel, vba

I hope you are fine and safe at this moment.

Can you help-me with this function below?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim xCombox As OLEObject
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xArr
    
    Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xCombox = xWs.OLEObjects("TempCombo")
    With xCombox
        .ListFillRange = ""
        .LinkedCell = ""
        .Visible = False
    End With
    If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
        Target.Validation.InCellDropdown = False
        Cancel = True
        xStr = Target.Validation.Formula1
        xStr = Right(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)
        If xStr = "" Then Exit Sub
        With xCombox
            .Visible = True
            .Left = Target.Left
            .Top = Target.Top
            .Width = Target.Width + 5
            .Height = Target.Height + 5
            .ListFillRange = xStr
            If .ListFillRange = "" Then
                xArr = Split(xStr, ";")
                Me.TempCombo.List = xArr
            End If
            .LinkedCell = Target.Address
            

            
        End With
        xCombox.Activate
        Me.TempCombo.DropDown
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub TempCombo_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 9
            Application.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        Case 13
            Application.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    End Select
End Sub
```

That works, but I need not to replace the cell value when some dropdown value is selected. I need to append the value to the cell with ";".

Below some images to help to illustrate:

**The select:**

[image: THE SELECT]

**The post select:**

[image]

**What I need**

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think is some detail that I can't resolve.

Comment: I think [this site](https://trumpexcel.com/select-multiple-items-drop-down-list-excel/) gives you a means to use VBA to create a multi-select dropdown.